# Discord.js v13 で特定のメッセージ検知

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

＊＊は暴言のため隠してます。
特定のメッセージが入った文を検知したら返信するコードを教えてください。

```
client.on("messageCreate", (msg) => {
    if (message.content.match === "＊＊") {
        msg.reply("暴言、誹謗中傷などはおやめください");
    }
});
```

Comment: どういうことについて知りたいのかをはっきりさせるため、知りたい問題をより具体的にしたり、追加の詳細を書き加えたりしてください。現状のままだと何についての質問なのかが分かりづらいです。

Answer (score 0):

私自身は node.js (JavaScript) や discord.js について詳しくないのであまり自信はありませんが、
質問のコードは比較 (`===`) とパターンマッチ (`match`) の記述がごっちゃになっているように見えます。

指定したキーワードを **含む** 場合に反応したいなら、以下のような記述になると思います。

[discord.jsで多機能bot作り - Qiita](https://qiita.com/hakureireimu111/items/1a840104bb29375e5011)

> ```
> client.on('message',message=>{
>   if (message.content.match(/この言葉が含まれている書くと/)) {
>     message.channel.send('ここのなかのメッセージを送る');
>   }
> });
> ```

`===` を使うと、指定したキーワードとメッセージの内容が (完全に) 一致した場合に反応する形になります。

> ```
> client.on('message', message=> {
>     if (message.content ==='この言葉を入力すると') {
>         message.channel.send ('この言葉で反応する');
>    }
> });
> ```